# How to find what commit contain a bug

Tags: git, version-control

I worked on my local computer, refactoring things(commits A,B,C,D), I always made sure that output files didn't change. After merging (commit I) I found that output files changed.

How can I find what exactly commit (E,F,G,H) is the reason of change?

```
A->B->C->D -I

\E->F->G->H/
```

Thank you!

Comment: The output of `git log --name-only` should show names of files that have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are after `git bisect`. You give it a bad and a good revision and then it checks out the middle between them, waits for you to tell it whether this commit is good, bad or unknown (e. g. because it does not compile in that commit) and then checks out the next middle of the remaining half. This binary search algorithm will very fast give you the commit that changed the output.

Also, if you can automate the process of determining whether the output files changed with a script, you can give that script to `git bisect` and it will run the script automatically to determine good, bad or unknown so you can just wait for the result.

Comment: This seems overkill.  Why not just parse the output of `git log`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth because he said the commits are too big to look use blame and he doesn't know what files changed, but only that the output changes. Also there are possibly more than 4 commits in question and above was only an example. Bisect is exactly the right tool for his request. :-)

Comment: Ah, I may have misinterpreted "output files changed" - initially assumed (s)he meant that some source-controlled files changed.  Of course, it's very likely (s)he means the results of some test, in which case you're exactly right.

Comment: Of course not, why should it? `D` is the parent of `I`, so the bad commit is `I`. You would mark `A` as good and `H` as bad e. g. if `A` still gave the right result and `H` the wrong one.